# How to use bind function on an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why my code isn't running, can someone give me some direction? 
When I run this code and check the console I get the error

" Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function "

```
var person = {
  firstName: "Jane",
  lastName: "Doe",
  getFullName: function() {
    var fullName = this.firstName + this.lastName;
    return fullName;
  }
}

(function() {
  console.log(this.getFullName());


}).bind(person);
```

Comment: Remember that `.bind(person)` does not invoke the function but return a new function. Adding `(function(){ ... }).bind(person)()` and running your code in the chrome developer tools console prints the name as expected...

Comment: @forrert I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're missing a semicolon (`;`). Without the semicolon at the end of your `person` declaration, your code effectively translates to this.

```
var person = { firstName: 'Jane', ... }(function() {
  console.log(this.getFullName());
}).bind(person);
```

Syntactically, you're attempting to call an object as a function then use the result of that function as another function.

Here's your corrected code:

```js
var person = {
  firstName: "Jane",
  lastName: "Doe",
  getFullName: function() {
    var fullName = this.firstName + this.lastName;
    return fullName;
  }
};

// Isn't called because `bind` returns a new function
(function() {
  console.log(this.getFullName());
}).bind(person);

// What you probably want to do
(function() {
  console.log(this.getFullName());
}).call(person);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could throw in a semicolon and a call with parenthesis, because the `var` statement has not ended and the object `person` is tried to call.

```js
var person = {
        firstName: "Jane",
        lastName: "Doe",
        getFullName: function() {
            var fullName = this.firstName + this.lastName;
            return fullName;
        }
    }; // insert semicolon here  


(function () {
    console.log(this.getFullName());
}).bind(person)(); // add parenthesis
```